# Generating lists populated with random objects

Tags: python, random

For the purposes of unit-testing in Python, I've written a very simple function for generating variable-length lists populated with random objects:

```
constructors = [
    object,
    dict,
    lambda: bool(randint(0, 1)),
    lambda: randint(1, 1000),
    lambda: ''.join(choice(digits) for _ in range(randint(1, 10)))
]

choices = (
    lambda _: choice(constructors)(),
    lambda off: fake_list(off),
    lambda off: tuple(fake_list(off))
)

def fake_list(off = None):
    '''Creates a list populated with random objects.'''
    off = (off or 0) + 1
    return [choice(choices)(off) for _ in range(max(randint(1, 10) - off, 0))]
```

List generated with this function typically look something like this:

```
[(269, '6'), [{}, 990, 347, <object object at 0x7f51b230b130>, {}, [{}, '91921063', 302, '0047953', {}, ()], True], '70262', True]
```

Do you see any problems with it? Is there a more efficient/elegant way of doing this that you could suggest?

Quality of the generated primitives (strings, integers) is not of priority (i.e. `string.digits` should be enough).

Comment: `off` reduces readability - it is a bit hard to follow what `(None or 0) + 1` might be. it is not documented in the docstring either. what is the intent of `off`?

Comment: `off` serves as an "annealing factor". That is, because the function may call itself, I need to ensure that I'm not calling forever. `off` is subtracted from randomly generated length of the list, so that it's shorter on each call.

Comment: that is quite smart, but would a name `recursion_depth` suit better? `off` is very generic to understand its meaning easily

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requirements may vary so I find it hard to use with the "hardcoded" `constructors`. Instead I would define a function that accept such constructors as an argument.

I would also define the function returning the list-comprehension as an inner function so the `off` parameter is hidden from the public interface (the end-user does not need to know such implementation details). Besides, `off` is a terrible name for such variable when all it does it to track the recursion depth, better call it `depth`, then.

An other thing that could be worth taking as parameter (even though a sensible default would make sense most of the time) is the maximum length of the inner lists (and thus the maximum allowed recursion level):

```
import random
from string import digits


def fake_list(items, max_size=10):
    """Create a list populated with random objects constructed from `items`"""

    choices = (
            lambda _: random.choice(items)(),
            lambda depth: random_list(depth),
            lambda depth: tuple(random_list(depth)),
    )

    def random_list(depth):
        return [
                random.choice(choices)(depth + 1)
                for _ in range(max(random.randint(1, max_size) - depth, 0))
        ]

    if max_size < 1:
        raise ValueError('minimal size of output should be at least 1')

    return random_list(0)


def test():
    constructors = [
        object,
        dict,
        lambda: bool(random.randint(0, 1)),
        lambda: random.randint(1, 1000),
        lambda: ''.join(
            random.choice(digits)
            for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))),
    ]

    print(fake_list(constructors))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

That way I can call:

```
fake_list([lambda: float('-inf'), lambda: range(random.randint(-100, -10), random.randint(10, 100)), set])
```

if I need to.

Comment: nice refactoring!